# Is there any way to fix the bug for Delvin's quest for the Thieves' Guild on PS4?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Since I am on PS4, I cannot use console commands, which means I can't  continue to the final Thieves' Guild quest (Under New Management). No matter how many quests I do for Vex and Delvin, he won't give me the special jobs. I have looked eveywhere, but everything is suggesting I use console commands, which I don't have access to. I don't want to give up the questline (he gave me one special job which was the Windhelm one), but now he won't give me any more.

How can I get Delvin to give me more special jobs so that I can finish the Thieves' Guild questline?

Answer (score 7):

It's not a glitch.

[Under New Management](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Under_New_Management) have specific city requirements.  In particular, it is almost always Markarth as the last because they have the lowest number of targets for thief jobs.

Look at the 4 special quests and determine which region is missing, then do only the jobs in those cities.

As for "choosing" the correct city, accept the quest, and if it is not the right city, quit the job and pick up another.  You get no penalties for quitting these jobs.

Comment: Markarth was the last city for 9/10 of my playthroughs.  There was one time I did all 3 other special quests and have yet to do a single mission in Markath.